# Forbid code to compile if some function is not called

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

Is there a way in C++ to forbid code to compile if the specific function was not called.

Imagine I have some class:

```
class CExample
{
public:
    void Init();
    void DoWork();

};
```

Is there a way to forbid calling **DoWork()** if the **Init()** function was not called for class object?

I want to forbid writing such a code:

```
CExample e;
e.DoWork();
```

and permit this version:

```
CExample e;
e.Init();
e.DoWork();
```

Can I reach this behaviour somehow with metaprogramming?

Comment: Can you not put the `Init` work into the constructor?

Comment: I just wondering whether I can do such trick. It's not some code that I have.

Comment: c++ classes should never have Init functions (unless they are private and unavailable to callers). RAII demands that an object is either fully constructed or an exception is thrown. There are good reasons for this.

Comment: If you do not own code and cannot change it, write a wrapper in which Init is called in the constructor and you your wrapper instead of the original class.

Comment: It's certainly not a part of the language spec to require a function to have been called in order for compilation or linking to be successful. One could probably modify a compiler to do what you're describing, but just as one would generally refrain from hammering a nail into ones own eye, one would refrain from this as well.

Comment: Notice that you cannot create an object without calling the constructor - which is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @mah I'm not sure even modifying the compiler helps, as it may be equivalent to the halting problem.  What do you do about code like: if (b) Init();

Answer (score 12):

You can just use a constructor instead of `Init`.

In his [notes about exception safety in the standard library, as appendix to the 3<sup>rd</sup> edition of The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe0.html), Bjarne Stroustrup discussed how using `init` functions is at odds with the notion of class invariant. It's generally Bad Practice™, mainly for that reason.

Some old GUI frameworks like Microsoft's MFC used `init` functions in order to do derived class specific initialization. There are [other techniques to do that](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom), including just [passing the required information up the construction chain](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/how-to-avoid-post-construction-by-using-parts-factories/) via arguments.

Answer (score 4):

No, that would be bad design. If it must be called for the object to be usable, it should be called in the constructor. After an object is constructed, all public methods should be callable-- the object should be fully constructed and ready for use.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time it is not known if `Init()` has been called before `DoWork()`. This can only be decided at runtime. Therefore metaprogramming will not be useful here.

Comment: A compiler could be modified to detect this at compilation or, at least, at link time (and for size optimization purposes, many do in at least certain circumstances). I'm not aware of any that will refuse to link in the event that something wasn't called though.

Comment: @mah My intuition tells me that this is equivalent to the halting problem at compile time.

Comment: @mah: I don't think so. The order in which the functions are called could depend on the input data. This is definitely a runtime thing.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Ahh yes, I was not taking the problem out to its ordering requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your init code into the constructor to enforce that the class is properly constructed. However if you really insist, and your init function really isn't polymorphic you can use CRTP with a protected constructor:

```
template <typename What>
class InitMe : public What
{
public:
    InitMe() : What() { this->Init(); }
};

class CExample
{
public:
    void Init() {}
    void DoWork() {}

protected:
    CExample() {}
};


int main()
{
    //CExample e;  // Error: protected constructor.

    InitMe<CExample> e;
    e.DoWork();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Cheers and hth. -Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35588706/4143855) and [Rob K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35588749/4143855) have both touched on, you most definitely want to have your `init` work performed in your class constructor. Having to call a separate function to ensure your class is properly ready is poor design.

However, that being said, you can *detect* if it's been called and act accordingly anyway:

```
void CExample::Init()
{
    // things
    ...
    init = true;
}

void CExample::DoWork()
{
    if (!init)
    {
        Init();
    }
}
```